# Converting a hexdecimal string to binary string

Tags: c#, binary, hex

I have `string`

```
w0 = "2B7E1516"
```

I want to convert it to a *binary* `string` in order to be

```
"00101011011111100001010100010110"
```

However i keep getting only `"101011011111100001010100010110"`:

```
w0 = "2B7E1516";
char paddingChar = '0';
w0 = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(w0, 16), 2).PadLeft(8, paddingChar);
```

The problem is in `2` it converts it to only `"10"` not to `"0010"`, how can i fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output string is a 32 bit number, so the last line should be:

```
wo = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(w0, 16), 2).PadLeft(32, '0');
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's convert each `char` within the `string` with padding to `4` digits:

```
 '0' ->    "0" -> "0000"
 '1' ->    "1" -> "0001"
 '2' ->   "10" -> "0010"  
  ...
 'F' -> "1111" -> "FFFF"
```

**Code:**

```
  string w0 = "2B7E1516";

  // Since we convert string char by char the initial string can be arbitrary long
  string result = string.Concat(w0.Select(c =>
    ('0' <= c && c <= '9' ? Convert.ToString(c - '0', 2) :
     'a' <= c && c <= 'f' ? Convert.ToString(c - 'a' + 10, 2) :
                            Convert.ToString(c - 'A' + 10, 2)).PadLeft(4, '0')));
```

Answer (score 2):

You only made it pad left 8 characters. If the resulting strings is more than 9 characters, it won't add more 0s to the left.

You should instead pad left by a multiple of 4. Which multiple of 4? That depends on the length of the hex string. Specifically, you should pad left by `w0.Length * 4`:

```
w0 = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(w0, 16), 2).PadLeft(w0.Length * 4, paddingChar);
```